# MYSQL: Returning AES encrypted data returns NULL

Tags: mysql, database, encryption, aes

I have a database with AES encrypted data, the encrypted data is stored in BLOBs, but when selecting data with the query below the return is `NULL`

```
SELECT aes_decrypt('firstname', 'key') AS firstname, aes_decrypt('lastname', 'key') AS lastname FROM orders
```

Comment: [If AES_DECRYPT() detects invalid data or incorrect padding, it returns NULL.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt)

Comment: If you mean column `lastname` don’t put it into single quotes. Now it’s a string.

Comment: @BillKarwin Wow, returns padding errors, it is a Padding oracle built into MySQL encryption! This is exactly why non-security people should not implement encryption. From this is seems one should not rely on MySQL encryption. Here is the funny part: all they had to do was ignore padding errors, they added code that made it insecure!